# Rails - conditional skip callbacks (after_save)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a method on `after_save` (and it has to be done after_save cause I use the id of the object), but I added a checkbox attribute to my form, and when I change it's value, naturally it pass for the callbacks to save. But in the situation that only that checkbox changed, I don't wanna call that method... wanna pass all the validations/callbacks. I could do the check if the `object.changes?` only has that checkbox attribute, but once the method is after_save, I don't have that information anymore. Can I do a check_method before_save, and there do something to skip the callbacks on save (how would it be)? Or there's another suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so if you want skip callback and validations for some reasons, rails has some methods for it. Those methods directly update the table by SQL, never goes through any callback and validations. Look the [list](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks).

Comment: @ArupRakshit but the problem is that it is on my form and the save method has to be called. But if only that attribute change, I wanted to check on before_save and then skip the another callbacks

Comment: Ok, then you can use like `person.name_changed?`, where `name` is the attribute of the `person` model.

Comment: @ArupRakshit as I said on carro answer, it doesn't work on after_save callback. That's why I would had to check on before_save and then skip the after_save method

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20200517230101/http://thelazylog.com/skip-activerecord-callbacks/

Answer (score 0):

You could know if an attribute was changed or will be changed adding `_changed` to the name of the attribute.

**Option 1**

```
after_save :some_method

def some_method
  if email_changed?
    // do some stuff
  end
end
```

**Option 2**

```
after_save :some_method, if: :email_changed?

def some_method
  // do some stuff
end
```

Comment: on after_save the attribute_changed? always return false. It only works on before_save callback

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.2.17. On after_save callbacks, changes always returns empty... only works on before_save for me

Comment: In 5 and 5.1 `attribute_changed?` should work as described. 5.2+ and it changes. Just if anybody comes reading old answers.

Answer (score 0):

In `after_save` and `after_commit` callbacks, you can use [`previous_changes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-previous_changes) to check the attributes that changed and short-circuit if the only attribute listed is the checkbox attribute.

Comment: tried that, but look: on before_save, object.changes is {"desabilita_integracao_sap"=>[false, true]} and after_save, object.previous_changes is { } (empty). I'm using rails 3. Does it work?

Comment: Haven't tried in Rails 3 although I know this existed back then. Will try later and report back. What exact version of Rails 3 are you using?

Comment: it's Rails 3.2.17. I believe it has that method, cause didn't raised some error, just returned a empty hash...